# Checking whether $10^{499} \equiv 1$ modulo $1997$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find the smallest number $x$ such that $10^x\equiv 1 \pmod{1997}$,

By Euler function we know $\phi(1997)=1996=4\times499$, so $x$ must be a divisor of $1996$, so I have to check whether $10^{499}\equiv 1 \pmod{1997}$, but I do not find a nice way to calculate it.

Comment: If you can't find an ingenious way to do it, [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is decently fast, even by hand.

Comment: Do you know about repeated squaring?

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity tells that neither $2$ nor $5$ is a QR, so $10$ is. Therefore the answer will be $\pm1$, but we need a bit more to decide.

Comment: Oh, the question really was about the order rather than the remainder. Sorry about not reading to the end.

Comment: @Arthur thank you maybe it is the only way to solve it.

Comment: While computing e.g. $225^2$ modulo $1997$ without a calculator is tedious, I agree with several commenters that repeated squaring or something similar is likely vital. I've checked in Python that $10^{499}=-1$, so $x=998$.

Comment: Quite a bit is known about [quartic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_reciprocity), but I'm not experienced enough with that to reach a conclusion. If anyone wants to play with those formulas, then $1997=29^2+34^2$ and $412$ is a modular square root of $-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In fact if I can find a square root of $10$ in some efficient way, I can check whether that square root is a quadratic residue. [I get $783=27 \cdot 29$ by inefficient methods]

Comment: Brainstorming ...
$$10^3\equiv -997\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^4\equiv -9970\equiv 15\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^7\equiv -997\cdot15\equiv 1021\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{14}\equiv 1021^2 \equiv 7\pmod{1997}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the order of $10\bmod 1997$ with pen and paper.

You begin by factoring $1997$ and realize it is a prime by checking it is not divisible by any prime under $\sqrt{1997} < 50$ ( so you only check $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,39,41,43,47$), which is a bit of work, but not too much.

We now know the multiplicative group $\bmod 1997$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{1996}$.

We factor $1996$ and get $1996 = 2^2 \cdot 499$,  in order to find that $499$ is prime we only need to check it is not divisible by $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23$.

In order to find what the order of $10\bmod 1997$ is we can find $v_2$ and $v_{499}$ of the order.

In order to find $v_{499}$ of the order we must check if $10^{1996/499} \equiv 1 \bmod 1997$. This part is easy because $10^4 = 10000$ is not $1\bmod 1997$. It follows $v_{499}$ of the order is $1$.

In order to find $v_2$ of the order we must check if $10^{1996/4}\equiv 1$ and if $10^{1996/2}\equiv 1 \bmod 1997$. First we check if $10^{499} \equiv 1 \bmod 1997$.

We use exponentiation by squaring. First we write $499$ in binary, it is $111110011$. Next we obtain the first $9$ residues for $10^{2^k}$ starting with $k=0$.

$10,100,15,225,700,735,1035,833,930$.

It follows $2^{449} \equiv 930 \cdot 833 \cdot 1035 \cdot 735 \cdot 700 \cdot 100 \cdot 10 \bmod 1997$.

This number turns out to be $1996\bmod 1997$.

Now in order to check $10^{1996/2}$ we just need to square the previous number, which happens to be $1$. It follows $v_2$ of the order is $1$.

Hence the order is $998$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a set a reusable and simple calculations
$$10^3\equiv -997\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^4\equiv -9970\equiv 15\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^7\equiv -997\cdot15\equiv 1021\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{14}\equiv 1021^2 \equiv 7\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{42}\equiv 7^3 \equiv 343\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{46}\equiv 343\cdot 15\equiv 1151\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{49}\equiv 1151 \cdot (-997) \equiv 728\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{490}\equiv 728^{10}\equiv 779^{5} \equiv 1750\cdot 1750\cdot779
\equiv 1099\cdot 779 \equiv 1405 \pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{498}\equiv  1405\cdot (15)^2 \equiv 599\pmod{1997}$$
$$10^{499}\equiv  5990 \equiv -1\pmod{1997}\tag{1}$$

---

It is [worth noting that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) $$ord_n(a) \mid \varphi(n)$$
So
$$ord_{1997}(10) \mid \varphi(1997)=2^2\cdot 449$$
considering $(1)$ and checking various combinations of $2,2,449$ we conclude that $x=ord_{1997}(10)=2\cdot 499$
$$10^{2\cdot499} \equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{1997}$$