# Find smallest $n$ so that $3^n-2^n$ is a multiple of $2015$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N}$  such that $3^n-2^n$ is a multiple of $2015$.
> Hint : $2015 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 31$

What i tried :

$$3^n\equiv2^n\pmod{2015}\begin{cases}  
3^n\equiv2^n  \pmod{5}\\                                    
3^n\equiv2^n \pmod{15}\\  
3^n\equiv2^n \pmod{31}\end{cases}$$

Using [Fermat's little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) :
$$\mod 5 \equiv \begin{cases}
3^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}\\
2^4\equiv1 \pmod{5}\\
2^4\equiv3^4 \pmod{5}
\end{cases}$$

- $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid blue]{2^2\equiv 3^2\pmod{5}}$

$$\mod 13\equiv\begin{cases}
3^{12} \equiv 1\pmod{13}\\
2^{12} \equiv 1\pmod{13}\\
2^{12}\equiv3^{12}\pmod{13}\end{cases}$$

- $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{2^4\equiv3^4\pmod{13}}$

$$\mod 31\equiv\begin{cases}
3^{30}\equiv1\pmod{31}\\
2^{30}\equiv1\pmod{31}\\
\boxed{3^{30} \equiv 2^{30}\pmod{31}}\end{cases}$$
since raising an exponent to an exponent works multiplicative that gives us some motivation to take the least common multiple of the boxed exponents $(2,4$ and $30)$ , the least common multiple of $2 ,4 ,30$ is equal to $60$ so we have :
$$2^{60}\equiv3^{60}\pmod{2015}$$
Now we have to check to see if $60$ is the smallest such exponent that allows us to get at this solution.

---

Checking to verify $60$ :
suppose $0<m<60$ is the smallest such number such that  $2^m\equiv3^m\pmod{2015}$.
division with remainder (division algorithm) we get :
$$60=m \cdot q+r \quad, 0\le r<m$$
Now we want to insert this version of $60$ into $2^{60}\equiv3^{60}\pmod{2015}$ we get :
$$\left(2^m\right)^q\cdot 2^r\equiv\left(3^m\right)^q\cdot 3^r\pmod{2015}$$
Note that $2$ and $3$ are invertible$\bmod{2015}$ so that means we can cancel $\left(2^m\right)^q$ and $\left(3^m\right)^q$ , we get
$$2^r \equiv 3^r\pmod{2015}$$
$\Rightarrow r\ne 0$ ( otherwise  the minimality of $m$ is contraicted) $\Rightarrow m|60$
so we get that $m=1,2,3,4,5,10,12,15,20,30.$
but after checking every number we can see that none of them works which tells us that $60$ is in fact the smallest such exponent.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Can you solve it for $5,13$ and $31$?

Comment: Also, welcome to the site. If you follow the recomendations in this link you will probably get much better results. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: You should really spend (at least) that 10 minutes before you ask here.

Comment: Does this answer your question islamm https://socratic.org/questions/can-you-find-the-smallest-n-as-3-n-2-n-can-be-devided-by-2015

Comment: @JitendraSingh  That's kind of a poor solution to the problem...trial and error is practically as good.  Starting $\pmod {31}$ at least gets you to a solution more efficiently.  In any case, it makes more sense to solve it mod $5,13,31$ separately and then intersect those solutions.

Comment: @Yorch I didin't checked the  solution I did a quick google check found the same question and posted it here

Comment: You want to find the order of $2\cdot3^{-1} \bmod n$ (where $n$ is 2015). In order to do that you take the least common multiple of the order of the elements $\bmod$ every prime power in the factorization of $n$.  I have a solution that sort of describes how that can be done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129665/checking-whether-10499-equiv-1-modulo-1997/4129766#4129766

Comment: The edits did not make it in before the question was closed.  I have voted to reopen it.  Your solution represents an excellent start but it is not complete.  Specifically, while you have shown that $n=60$ works, you have not shown that it is minimal.  To show that, I suggest examining the $\pmod {31}$ case to show that any such $n$ would have to be divisible by $30$.  That would only leave you one number to check.

Comment: The solution looks almost good but I think you need to use some words to say why it all works. The numeric answer is correct.

Comment: @islamm: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In particular, to display "$2^n$" type "`$2^n$`", and to display "$3^n = 2^n \pmod{2015}$" type "`$3^n = 2^n \pmod{2015}$`".

Comment: [Here is the AoPS solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1742187p11330313) In particular, hard work will be required in the $31$ case.

Comment: Hi! I've partially edited your question so you can see how to use $\LaTeX$ to format it. Please take a look. I've also reverted to a more informative title (cf. @user21820 comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good start.  But notice that $2^2\equiv 3^2 \pmod{5}$ and $2^4 \equiv 3^4 \pmod{13}$, for instance.  So some number smaller than (and dividing) $60$ is the answer.

Edit:  I'm wrong here.  Because of what I wrote, I thought the answer might be smaller than $60$, but it turns out to be $60$.   I should have said, "the answer *might* be smaller than $60$.